# How to split variable from linq query result

Tags: c#

I want to split the data result from linq query , let's say from this code where I write

```
            string[] items;
            var data = from c in db.CMRTables where c.Id.Equals(17776) select new {  c.Auth, c.amount };
            string s = String.Join(",", data);
            items = s.Split(',');
            MessageBox.Show(items[0]);
```

It will return { Auth = 80231252 , amount = 8888888 } , I want to split the value so I can store it to variable ,

My expected result is 80231252 and 8888888 only , when I split it , how to do it? and what I select is basically not 2 values , but more than 2 values or I can say like 19 values

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you explain more clearly the result that you want?

Comment: @Sweeper , i want to take the value of auth and amount , but i dont want to include the Auth = and amount = , because i want to save the value in variable..

from what i did with the linq , the result is { Auth = 80231252 , amount = 8888888 }, my expected result is the variable is 8023152,8888888 so i can split based on "," only , if i split based on "," with the result of { Auth = 80231252 , amount = 8888888 }, it will return { Auth = 80231252 and amount = 8888888}

Comment: var data = (from c in db.CMRTables where c.Id.Equals(17776) select new {  c.Auth, c.amount }).FirstOrDefauld();
And Just Take `data.Auth + "," + data.amount`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why cant you just,

```
var data = (from c in db.CMRTables where c.Id.Equals(17776) select new { c.Auth, c.amount }).FirstOrDefault();
var ExpectedResult = data.Auth + "," + data.amount;
```

Comment: Eh , what ?i dont know i can do that here , sorry, but it works perfectly fine

Comment: still learning this language , and i just get the basics from university , sorry

Answer (score 1):

Split on ',', then use enumerator to process each entry:

```
string[] items = s.Split(',')
                  .Select(keyVal => keyVal.Split('=')[1].Trim())
                  .ToArray();
```

This above:

- splits string `s` using separator `','` into temporary array (`Split()`)
- for each item in this temporary array gets this item as `keyVal` string and process those using formula on right side of `'=>'` (`Select()`)
- converts the result to `string[]` array.

Comment: what is keyVal redirecting to?

Comment: This is parameter in lambda-expression, you can name it as you want, like `qq => qq.Split('=')[1].Trim()`

Comment: hmm cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnurable<string> to string[]

Comment: it works now , thankyou , i think i will go to the answer from Sushant because it is more simple , still appreciate it , and thankyou for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex for the purpose.

```
var numbers = Regex.Matches(str, @"\d+")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(x=>x.Value);
```

If you want the result as `List<Long>`

```
var numbers = Regex.Matches(str, @"\d+")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(x=>long.Parse(x.Value));
```